# Ok to validate within query document?

Tags: node.js, validation, node-mongodb-native

Which is a better trade-off for validation of a common field?

`user.groups = [someIds]`

---

`db.posts.findOne({ _id: someId, group: someOtherId })`

if there's no document returned then I can assume the user is
querying for a document outside of their group

--- OR ---

```
db.posts.findOne({ _id: someId }, function(err, doc){
  if (!~user.groups.indexOf(doc.group)){
    // not validated
  }
})
```

Comment: By validation, are you referring to whether the user has permission to view a post based on their groups? The answer here depends on whether you need to tell the user anything about the post they don't have access to (i.e. a more specific "you don't have permission to view this post" versus just a generic "404: post not found"). Either approach can work depending on what you want to do in your application  UI.

Comment: Ah, yes. You're right. I have a few post fetch routes which do need to respond with a 403 and 404 vs only a 404.

Comment: @Stennie So, assuming that the user already has all the information about what they can and cannot view, hence the client-side can effectively handle nearly all validation, would it make sense to integrate the the validation as part of the queries and add those validation fields to the indexes?